# Not sure why my custom UICollectionViewCell isn’t working?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I’m coding a mock messaging app in Swift Playgrounds for iPad. Every time I run the Playground, I get the error “There was a problem running this page. Check your code for problems. If you are stuck, delete everything on this page and try again”. Here’s what I have so far. It’s fairly simple, I’m not sure what I could be doing wrong.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ChatView : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.register(ChatLogMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! ChatLogMessageCell
            cell.messageTextView.text = "sample message text"
            return cell
        }

}



class ChatLogMessageCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    let messageTextView : UITextView = {
        let textView = UITextView()
        //textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 36)
        textView.text = "sample message"
        return textView
    }()

    func setupViews(){
        addSubview(messageTextView)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ChatView()
```

Comment: Playgrounds tends to be buggy. Have you tried running this in a normal project?

Comment: You didn't set any constraints for the textview?

Comment: Unfortunately this has to be done in a Playground. It’s a submission for Apple’s WWDC Student Challenge, and it’s a requirement that all submissions be Playgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this solution.**

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ChatView : UICollectionViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView?.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .green
        return cell
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ChatView(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
```

[image: You can check result of above code]

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives the same error message

Comment: Are you checking this in Xcode 11.4.1, As This is working perfect in my playground

Comment: Restarted everything and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome buddy, Please accept my answer if your problem resolved.